# R Session Aborted (R "OncoBayes2" package), how to fix it?

Tags: r, rstudio

when i try to require R package "OncoBayes2", R studio pops up "R Session Aborted". [image]

i tried re-install the package, or try to require it in R software directly instead of using R studio, it still exist.